# Arduino two Ethernet shields

Tags: ethernet

Is it possible to connect two Ethernet shields to arduino? And if yes, how can I distinguish them in the code?

Comment: You need to move the SS pin for one of the shields (Arduino pin 10). That way you can select which shield you want to talk to.

Comment: I don't think you can do this because the Ethernet.begin statement isn't an instance of Ethernet so I don't think you can do this.

Comment: Technically it is possible. Maybe you will have to  write your own library. But... Why? Why do you need two ethernet shields? I'm pretty sure the main problem is another one... Please tell us what you really want to achieve, so smarter solutions can be suggested (see [The XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/)). I'm telling you this because even if you have two shields you won't be able to do much work with them...

Answer (score 4):

The ENC28J60 Shields have a Chip-Select-Pin (CS) so you could select between the two shields with this.

[image: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/fc/SPI_three_slaves.svg]

I'm using the EN28j60 with the Ethercard library and I'm not sure if this could handle two Ethernet shields because you have to **set the CS pin at init on the first call in the function**, and can't change it at runtime.

Comment: As I know you can High or Low any pin at runtime.

Comment: As far as I know, the library doesn't have any provision to use multiple shields/modules because I tried to do it and it kept disconnecting.

Let me know if you had any success doing that.